# Building shared FFTW library for Android

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, fftw

I am trying to build a shared library of FFTW by means of the following script:

```
INSTALL_DIR="`pwd`/jni/fftw3"
SRC_DIR="`pwd`/../fftw-3.3.4"

cd $SRC_DIR

NDK_ROOT=/path_to_android/Sdk/ndk-bundle

export PATH="$NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:$PATH"
export SYS_ROOT="$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/"
export CC="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$SYS_ROOT"
export LD="arm-linux-androideabi-ld"
export AR="arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
export RANLIB="arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib"
export STRIP="arm-linux-androideabi-strip"

mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR
./configure --enable-shared --host=arm-eabi --build=i386-linux --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR LIBS="-lc -lgcc" --enable-float

make
make install

exit 0
```

However, after executing the script I always only receive a static FFTW library even though I am using the *enable-shared* parameter. Is there any other way to generate the shared library file?
I really need a shared library since Android Studio demands a shared library to compile additional JNI sources.

**Update:**
Based on @bullsy's answer, I could build the shared library by chaning the host parameter to `--host=arm-linux-androideabi`. The resulting problem is that FFTW generates a versioned shared library with library files `libfftw.so.3` and `libfftw.so.3.4.4`. I found a [tutorial](http://shellblade.net/android-cpp.html) that shows how to convert these files into `.so` files. While working on `libfftw3.so` or `libfftw3.so.3`, I always received the error that *file is not a (regular) file* so I tried everything on `libfftw3.so.3.4.4`:

```
rpl -R -e libfftw3.so.3 libfftw3_3.so libfftw3.so.3.4.4 
mv libfftw3.so.3.4.4 libfftw3_344.so
ln -sfn libfftw3_344.so libfftw3.so.3
mv libfftw3.so.3 libfftw3_3.so
```

I had to add the `ln` command manually. Without changing the symlink, Gradle could not find `libfftw3_3.so` during the building process of the apk.
So my application is running now with the shared libs but it is also possible to generate shared FFTW libs with single precision (**-enable-float**)?

---

Another approach was to take the static library file and to build a shared library file by means of an *Android.mk* and *ndk-build*:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := fftw3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := fftw3/lib/libfftw3.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_MODULE    := fftw_wrapper
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /path_to_fftw_headers/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /pat_to_wrapper/fftw_wrapper.h
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := fftw_wrapper.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := fftw3f
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But this approach always returns *undefined reference* errors, e.g. undefined reference to 'fftw_malloc'. I have also tried it without the *--build* parameter as it is explained in this question: [Using FFTW on Android undefined references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701595/using-fftw-on-android-undefined-references)

Whenever I use the static library, my application runs fine, even when I statically link the *fftw_wrapper* in the *Android.mk*. However, since my C/C++ imports are all defined in the app Gradle file of Android Studio, I do not want to change back to Android.mk files. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
--host=arm-linux-androideabi
```

instead. This tells configure 'Hey, I'm building for a linux variant', which makes shared libraries the default choice.

Comment: Thank you! With this parameter I can successfully create the shared library but I have to delete the _--enable-float_ parameter. However, if I load the library in my application. I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: libfftw3.so.3 not found`. Can I tell FFTW to create only one file or how am I able to load that additional file? If I enable float, I am getting a lot of undefined references to `fftwf_codelet_XX` files like `fftwf_codelet_n1_2` or `fftwf_codelet_hc2cb_2`. Is it also possible to enable float for the shared FFTW library for Android?